# paramiko Error Servname not supported for ai_socktype

Tags: paramiko

I am unable to connect to other server through paramiko:

```
import paramiko
import sys
import os

hostname = 'server1'
port = 22
username = 'root'
password = 'password'`enter code here`
def deploy_key(key, hostname, username, password):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname, username, password)
    client.exec_command('mkdir -p ~/.ssh/')
    client.exec_command('echo "%s" > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' % key)
    client.exec_command('chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys')
    client.exec_command('chmod 700 ~/.ssh/')

key = open(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')).read()
deploy_key(key, hostname, username, password)
```

Here was the output:

```
socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

Answer (score 17):

The problem is with the call to `client.connect()`. It expects `port` to be second parameter and to be an integer, whereas you are giving username (string) as second parameter.
Try replacing that with below line.

```
client.connect(hostname, username=username, password=password)
```

That should work.