# Error in executing paramiko

Tags: python, linux, sockets, ssh

While executing the following code, I am getting a traceback

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import paramiko
command1= "cat /etc/fidelity-release"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("sbanlab1","user","passwd")
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exex_command(command1)
ssh.close()
```

The traceback:

```
socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC,     socket.SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

Comment: I think you need to clean up the code formatting - its hard to read ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251258/paramiko-error-servname-not-supported-for-ai-socktype

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh.connect("sbanlab1", username="user", password="passwd")
```

Here is the definition of `paramiko.SSHClient.connect` method (from [Paramiko client.py source file](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/client.py))

```
def connect(self, hostname, port=SSH_PORT, username=None, password=None, [...])
```

The way you are using the `connect` method is equivalent as following

```
ssh.connect("sbanlab1", port="user", username="passwd")
```